# DataGridView Datatable Copy-Keep-Add-Update rows

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview, datatable

I am developing Windows application (environment: Visual Studio 2010 and C#)
I use a datagridview with records completed by datatable dt:

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

This datatable has 20 columns with 1 identity column - column[0] = autonumber, and  column[1] called “RecordChecked” implemented as Boolean (checkbox).

I need to solve next problems:

1. Select rows filtered by column[2] (in code example: DrawingNo='DM-3012');
2. Keep these records
3. Add exactly the same records below existing but update column[2] with different value like DrawingNo='DM-3013' (so we’ll have twice more records)

I started from copying records from one datatable into another (see code below) – this code works ok, but then stacked how to add copied records below existing and then update them:

```
DataTable dtSource = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource);

DataTable dtTarget = new DataTable();

dtTarget = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Clone();

DataRow[] rowsToCopy;

rowsToCopy = ((DataTable)dataGridView1.DataSource).Select("DrawingNo='DM-3012'");

foreach (DataRow temp in rowsToCopy)
{
      dtTarget.ImportRow(temp);
}

dt = dtTarget;
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a good approach to this problem.
1. Create Stored Procedure (mySP).

This SP creates temp table where we located all records selected with clause 'WHERE DrawingNo = @CopyFrom'.
Then this SP updates temp table with statement like:
    UPDATE #TempTbl1 SET RecChecked = 0, DrawingNo = @CopyTo WHERE DrawingNo = @CopyFrom. 
Then SP inserts updated records from temp table into the main table.
Finally SP drops temp table and selects all needed records from the main table.
2.  Now we can run this SP in app and bind data to datagridview like:

```
//Run SP
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("mySP", con))
{
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CopyFrom", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value =   sValueFrom;       
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@CopyTo", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sValueTo;           
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}

//Create SELECT statement
string strSelect = "SELECT Recid, RecChecked, DrawingNo, ...  FROM Tbl1 WHERE DrawingNo = '" + sValueTo + "'"

//fill dataadapter
sda = new SqlDataAdapter(@strSelect, con);
dt = new DataTable();
sda.Fill(dt);
```

That works!